# Use linq to group datatable and take first of every group

Tags: linq, datatable

I am attempting to group a data table by type, then order it by date, and take the first of every group.

DataTable

Type A    1/10/2011 
Type B    1/23/2014 
Type B    7/1/2013 
Type A    5/4/2014

I would like the following returned:

Type A  5/4/2014 
Type B  1/232014

I have the following linq, but it's only returning this

Type A 5/4/2014

What am I doing wrong?

```
 DataTable dt = docData.AsEnumerable()
                  .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Type")) 
                  .Select(group => group
                  .OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<string>("EffectiveDate"))
                  .First())
                  .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Your code should work fine. Make sure that you have `Type A` and `Type B` in your table `docData` because it appears there is only one value `Type A` in your `docData` table. **Also**, you should use `DateTime` type column for `EffectiveDate`. You will not get the proper order based on date stored as string.

Comment: @Habib, thanks for your comment and reassurance that I was writing my linq correctly. I've been debugging for a while, and finally found an error in another part of my code. I'll leave my question  up for future reference for others. Thanks again.